# Произведение матриц (не могу разобраться, что делаю не так)

Tags: python

```
    def func(array_1,array_2):
    result = 0
    arr_1 = len(array_1)
    arr_2 = len(array_1[0])
    arr_3 = len(array_2)
    arr_4 = len(array_2[0])
    if arr_2 != arr_3:
        pass
    else:
        arr_5 = [[0]*arr_1]*arr_4
        for i in range(arr_1):
            for j in range(arr_4):
                for k in range(arr_2):
                    result = a[i][k] * b[k][j]
                arr_5[i][j] = result
        return arr_5


a = [[1, 2, 3],  #столбец
     [4, 5, 6]
     ]

b = [[7, 4],    #сторока
     [5, 1],
     [4, 8]]

print(func(a,b))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас сразу две ошибки в коде.

```
arr_5 = [[0]*arr_1]*arr_4
```

Тут у вас получается `arr_4` копии списка `[0]*arr_1`. То есть ссылки на одни и те же вложенные списки, а не независимые друг от друга списки. Лучше создавать нулевую матрицу так, чтобы её элементы были точно независимыми друг от друга объектами:

```
arr_5 = [[[0] for _ in range(arr_1)] for _ in range(arr_4)]
```

Вторая ошибка тут:

```
for k in range(arr_2):
    result = a[i][k] * b[k][j]
arr_5[i][j] = result
```

Видите - `result` заново присваивается на каждой итерации цикла, а он должен в этом цикле накапливаться:

```
result = 0
for k in range(arr_2):
    result += a[i][k] * b[k][j]
arr_5[i][j] = result
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь лучше библиотекой `numpy`.
Я списки `a` и `b` преобразовал в *numpy-объект*, но лучше сразу создавать объекты `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3],  #столбец(преобразуем список списков в numpy-объект)
     [4, 5, 6]
     ])

b = np.asarray([[7, 4],    #сторока(преобразуем список списков в numpy-объект)
     [5, 1],
     [4, 8]])
     
print(np.dot(a, b)) # матричное умножение
```

Подробнее про `numpy` и его возможности [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/numpy/1.html)